# Why JQuery cycle does not work

Tags: jquery, cycle

I want use of JQuery cycle.

I had designed this simple page, but the JQuery cycle doesn't work.

Does anyone have idea?

tnx

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Basic Example 1</title>
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.pics').cycle('fade');
    });

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pics">
      <img src="http://davealger.info/i/1.jpg"  width="200" height="200"  />
      <img src="http://davealger.info/i/2.bmp"  width="200" height="200"  />
      <img src="http://davealger.info/i/3.png"  width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Did you try referencing jQuery before jQuery Cycle (reordering your 2 script references)?

Comment: I referencing jQuery before jQuery Cycle and it's work. Tnx so much